# Getting text value of a UILabel in the selected cell in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview which loads data for an sqlite database and displays them in sections.

Its cell of the tableview has three labels for displaying text.

My question is can I get the text value of a label in the selected cell in prepareForSegue, so i can pass it to the detail view?

Comment: I found the solution:

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:999];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You should set the `tag` property on each of the UILabels in your table view's prototype cell (you can do this in the storyboard) so you can identify them in your `prepareForSegue:` code.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // sender is the table view cell that was selected
    UITableViewCell *cell = sender;

    // get the text of the label in the cell with tag 0
    NSString *firstLabelText = [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0] text];

    // now use that text to set a property on your segue's destinationViewController...

}
```